# Draw WFS with latlong coordinates to canvas in Java

Tags: java, swing, processing, gis, geotools

I am very new to Java programming, I would appreciate any kind of help.
So I want to display a set of lat-long coordinates (more than 50 coordinates) in Java-based canvas (e.g JFrame, Processing) from a WFS server. I have managed to parse lat-long value and print it to the console. Now I'm stuck in how to bring the lat-long coordinates to the screen coordinates (I'd like to draw it on 1000x500 size). I've tried to search for the reference but couldn't find the simplest one for a beginner like me. Here is the current part of my code :

```
String[] splitc = coord.split(",");
                    String lon = splitc[0];
                    String lat = splitc[1];
                    //parse string to float
                    float loncoord=Float.parseFloat(lon);
                    float latcoord=Float.parseFloat(lat);
```

1. Can I transfer the coordinates from the WFS to screen coordinates using *world2screen.translate* of Geotools library as in https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/axis.html ?
2. In processing, there is a map() function (https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) to transfer from a range to another. I've tried it but it didn't work on my IDE.
3. One super noob question, I'm trying to store the WFS connection in a function so I can call it in another class, should I store it in static void or use "return"?

If someone can provide an example of a similar task, that would be very helpful. Thanks (Sara)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use this formula instead:

   ```
   float x = ((WIDTH/360.0) * (180 + loncoord));
   float y = ((HEIGHT/180.0) * (90 - latcoord));
   ```
2. It should work... Note that it returns a `float` and takes 5 arguments of the form:
   `map(input, inputMin, inputMax, outputMin, outputMax)`
3. You only want to create the connection once, so you're left with two viable options: defining the connection as a static variable of a static class, or defining the connection as an instance variable of a class following the [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton) pattern.

   Assuming you chose the former approach, the method that returns the connection variable should therefore be `static` but not `void`:

   ```
   public static connectionType getConnection() {
       return connectionObject;
   }
   ```

   ... where `connectionType` is the datatype of the connection.

Comment: could you elaborate your formula? I am a bit confused about the axis in latlong vs screen coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a GeoTools `WFSDataStore`, this code builds up the getCapabilities string if the user has given just a URL to the service endpoint and handles authentication if needed. The datastore is stored in a field of the class:

```
  public FetchWFS(String url, String user, String passwd) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    if (!user.isEmpty()) {
      auth = true;
    }
    baseURL = new URL(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nvp = URLEncodedUtils.parse(baseURL.toURI(), "UTF-8");
    NameValuePair service = new BasicNameValuePair("service", "wfs");
    NameValuePair request = new BasicNameValuePair("request", "getCapabilities");
    NameValuePair version = new BasicNameValuePair("version", "2.0.0");
    HashMap<String, NameValuePair> parts = new HashMap<>();
    parts.put(service.getName(), service);
    parts.put(request.getName(), request);
    parts.put(version.getName(), version);
    for (NameValuePair part : nvp) {

      if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("SERVICE")) {
        // We don't care what they think this should be
      } else if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("REQUEST")) {
        // This must be getCapabuilities so we ignore them
      } else if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("VERSION")) {
        System.out.println("Changing version to " + part.getValue());
        parts.put(version.getName(), part);
      } else {
        parts.put(part.getName(), part);
      }
    }

    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme(baseURL.getProtocol());
    builder.setHost(baseURL.getHost());
    builder.setPort(baseURL.getPort());
    builder.setPath(baseURL.getPath());
    List<NameValuePair> p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.addAll(parts.values());
    builder.setParameters(p);
    // builder.addParameter("viewparams", "q:\"mySolrQuery\"");
    URI uri = builder.build();
    System.out.println(uri);
    baseURL = uri.toURL();
    // fetch the DataStore
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, baseURL);
    // params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.WFS_STRATEGY.key, "mapserver");
    if (auth) {
      params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.USERNAME.key, user);
      params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.PASSWORD.key, passwd);
    }
    // params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.WFS_STRATEGY.key, "mapserver");
    datastore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
  }
```

Once you have a DataStore (of any type) you can get a list of available 
featureTypes and then add one (or more) of them to a map:

```
        JMapFrame frame = new JMapFrame();
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        String[] names = datastore.getNames();
        featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(names[0]); //fetch first featureType
        schema = featureSource.getSchema();

        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(schema);
        this.layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);

        map.addLayer(layer);
        frame.enableToolBar(true);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

The [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) [Quickstart Tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) will help you get started with simple mapping, and the [Map Styling tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/map/style.html) will allow you to generate a prettier map when you want more than a simple black and white default map.

Comment: Thanks, but can we make an interactive map using JMapframe? For instance, if the user clicks on the point, the attributes will appear.

Comment: The JMapFrame tool bar includes an "identify" tool that does that by default. You can of course reuse that action any where you need it.